# WPF DataGrid flicker when using proportional column sizes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, flicker

I have a customized datagrid control that dynamically creates columns depending on various circumstances.

Originally I was using fixed column sizes as such.

```
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(entity.DisplaySize);
```

This is in a foreach loop.  However, we decided that we need to ensure that we never have horizontal scrolling, so I change it to the following so that the columns always fit inside the datagrid and they maintain their size proportionally to each other.

```
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(entity.DisplaySize, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

However, now when the datagrid draw, or is redrawn, there is flicker.  It looks like it is initially creating the datagrid with all columns at the minimum size of 20 and then once all columns are created it expands them to fill the area.  This behavior was not present with the previous method of providing precise column widths.

I have played with various virtualization settings to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas please?